# performed PCA on a data set for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, classification, pca

I have performed PCA on my data set and found out that 95% of variability has been covered by the first three principal components. I wanted to perform a logistic regression on the data set. What do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Train the model as usual with those three components. We have to do the same thing on test data too. Your classification job can be done.

Note: By training a model with PCA components. You don't get feature importance. If that is fine, you can proceed with those three components. Else, those components can be useful for just visualization purpose.

Comment: any online resources to help me what I need to do step by step?

Comment: I found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60) as most appropriate for your problem. This Explains step by step process of implementing PCA and finally used logistic regression for classification. Hope this helps.